# Javascript array element count

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I Have a javascript array

```
var array=["83487","83488","83489","83490","83491"];
```

I want to get the Count of this array
How can I get the count
here it is 5.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Answer (score 3):

```
array.length;
```

or

```
array["length"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `length` property:

```
var array=["83487","83488","83489","83490","83491"];
alert(array.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
 function myFunction()
 {
  var sample = ["83487","83488","83489","83490","83491"];
  alert(sample.length);
 }
 </script>
```

[Sample](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_length_array)

Comment: `var Number` ??.. what if user called this `new Number(10)` ?

Answer (score 0):

use  array.length; it will return you the number of elements in array